# std::ofstream sometimes fails to open file in a 'for' loop

Tags: c++, ostream

Here is the minimal reproducible code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const string TEST_FILE_PATH = "output.txt";

void write_to_file(string path, string line);
void generate_passwords(string file);

int main()
{
    generate_passwords(TEST_FILE_PATH);
    return 0;
}

void generate_passwords(string file)
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int len = 1; len <= 100; len++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            write_to_file(file, to_string(count) + " : ");
            count++;
        }
    }
}

void write_to_file(string path, string line)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(path, ios::out | ios::app);

    cout << "writing line : " << line << endl;

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "file is open " << endl;
        file << line << '\n';
        cout << "written..." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "FILE NOT OPEN" << endl;
    }

    file.close();
}
```

This is a stripped-down version of my full code, and it reproduces the same error.

With this code, I expect exactly 10,000 lines to be written to `output.txt`. However, it sometimes skips a random number of lines:

[image]

See how it skips numbers 6466 to 6509.

The console prints `"FILE NOT OPEN"` for these numbers.

This rarely happens with fewer iterations, but occurs very often with large numbers of iterations.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need `file.close();` It'll close itself when `file´ goes out of scope.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them then immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ofstream file; file.open(path, ios::out | ios::app);` to `ofstream file(path, ios::out | ios::app);`

Comment: @PeteBecker also, explicitly specifying `ios::out` for a `std::ofstream` is redundant and can be omitted: `ofstream file(path, ios::app);` since `std::ofstream` will force `ios::out` internally. That is what the `o` in `ofstream` stands for

Comment: @DannyG What is the point of opening and closing the same file 10000 times in rapid succession? Why not open the file once and leave it open until all 10000 lines are written? Most likely, something else on your system (anti-virus, etc) is accessing the file during the time that `ofstream` is failing to open the file. You can verify that with filesystem monitoring tools, like SysInternals Process Monitor on Windows.

Comment: I'd avoid `std::endl` when writing to file (or in any case)

Comment: @RemyLebeau I moved my code to write to file into the generate_passwords function and this seems to have worked. I like to keep my code in separate functions, thus why I have a write_to_file function and I call it every time. I never considered the possibility of the file being accessed by some other process during runtime, so thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @DannyG "*I like to keep my code in separate functions, thus why I have a write_to_file function*" - that is perfectly fine. In that case, I would suggest opening the `ofstream` in `generate_passwords()` and then passing the `ofstream` to `write_to_file()`, eg: `void generate_passwords(const string &path)
{ ofstream file(path, ios::app); ... write_to_file(file, ...); ... } void write_to_file(ostream &file, const string &line) {  ... file << line << '\n'; ... }`

Comment: I have a similar issue, and I'm a bit disapointed this hasn't been solved :( ! I generate dozens of files at once, and some of the file fail to open on first try (only when they don't exist yet). I fixed this by ensuring that when the `write_to_file` method fails to open a file, it would call itself to try again. It works. The files that fail to open on first try always manage to open on second try (assuming it *should* be possible to create and write in). This is pretty weird, and I would really like to know what's up with this behaviour.